# Adding the uri.js bower component breaks my Grunfile.js, which dies thinking the uri.js directory is a file. How to fix?

Tags: build, gruntjs, uri, bower, yo

The Yeoman generated Gruntfile.js dies during a grunt build with:

```
Running "rev:dist" (rev) task
dist/public/app/app.js >> b90d2f58.app.js
dist/public/app/vendor.js >> 2deb5480.vendor.js
Warning: Unable to read "dist/public/bower_components/uri.js" file (Error code: EISDIR). Used --force, continuing.
```

Clearly it is interpreting the uri.js component directory as a file!  One simple fix is to rename the uri.js component to uri_js or something similar.  But rather than do that, is there an easy switch to add to the utility that does the Hashing to know that 'uri.js' is not a file???  I already tried adding "filter: 'isFile'" to every place in the Gruntfile that has *.js as a pattern, to no avail.

Anyone who has already seen this, your help is appreciated. For now I am simply doing grunt build --force.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally discovered that one can exclude this bower_component from the rename process.  The key is that order of the files in the rev piece is dependent on the order of selection.  So I modified this section of my Gruntfile.js  ... and all is well.

```
// Renames files for browser caching purposes
rev: {
  dist: {
    files: {
      src: [
        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.js',
        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.css',
        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/fonts/*',
        '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/bower_components/uri.js'
      ]
    }
  }
```

The crucial addition was this last piece:

```
        '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/bower_components/uri.js'
```

I hope this helps someone else with with this issue!